# How to make divs align vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

I have 6 shop item divs and i want them to align perfectly in the main div with 3 on top and 3 on bottom like this https://gyazo.com/c01820bcfb2ac1adf4e4bc86111bdba5 
 This is a codepen 
https://codepen.io/mouhibd/pen/NWgKNMQ

```
html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    background-color: rgb(240, 231, 231);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 1500px;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: rgba(190, 223, 7, 0.788);
    color: white;
    margin: 30px;
}

header h1, nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
}

footer {
    padding: 10px;
}
main h2{
    text-align: center;
}
main{
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 270px;
}

.product {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern solution to this is to use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) combining with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Use grid for 2-dimensional layout (e.g. cards). Use flexbox for 1-dimensional layout (e.g. aside & main). I just added a few lines to your code and it already works fine.

```css
html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    background-color: rgb(240, 231, 231);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 1500px;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: rgba(190, 223, 7, 0.788);
    color: white;
    margin: 30px;
}

header h1, nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
}

footer {
    padding: 10px;
}
main h2{
    text-align: center;
}
main{
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 270px;
}

.product {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Tech Store</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Shop</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <input type="search" placeholder="search...">
</header>
<div class="container">
  <aside>
      <h2>Shop By:</h2>

      <section>
          <ul>
              <h3>Category</h3>
              <hr>
              <li>All items</li>
              <li>Cameras</li>
              <li>Laptops</li>
              <li>Phones</li>
              <li>Accessories</li>
              <li>Other</li>
          </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
          <ul>
              <h2>Price ($)</h2>
              <hr>
              <li>1-9</li>
              <li>10-29</li>
              <li>30-59</li>
              <li>60-99</li>
              <li>+100</li>
          </ul>
      </section>
  </aside>
  <main>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>All items</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-grid">
        <div class="product">
            <a href="xbox.html"><img src="images/controller.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
            <a href="xbox.html">
                <h4>Game Controller</h4>
            </a>
            <p>79.95$</p>
            <p>Awesome game controller <br> for xbox!</p>
            <a href="xbox.html">
                <p>More Info</p>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html">
                <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="headphones.html"><img src="images/headphones.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
            <a href="headphones.html">
                <h4>White Headphones</h4>
            </a>
            <p>54.95$</p>
            <p>Awesome white <br> Headphones </p>
            <a href="headphones.html">
                <p>More Info</p>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html">
                <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="camera.html"><img src="images/camera.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
            <a href="camera.html">
                <h4>Cannon Camera</h4>
            </a>
            <p>645.95$</p>
            <p>Awesome Camera <br> by Cannon</p>
            <a href="camera.html">
                <p>More Info</p>
            </a>
            <a href="index.html">
                <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
            </a>
        </div>
      <div class="product">
          <a href="microphone.html"><img src="images/microphone.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
          <a href="microphone.html">
              <h4>Yeti Microphone</h4>
          </a>
          <p>119.95$</p>
          <p>Awesome Blue <br> Yeti Microphone</p>
          <a href="microphone.html">
              <p>More Info</p>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html">
              <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <a href="cables.html"><img src="images/cables.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
          <a href="cables.html">
              <h4>Cables</h4>
          </a>
          <p>10.95$</p>
          <p>Awesome Cables Available <br> In Different Lengths</p>
          <a href="cables.html">
              <p>More Info</p>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html">
              <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product">
          <a href="lenses.html"><img src="images/lenses.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
          <a href="lenses.html">
              <h4>Camera Lenses</h4>
          </a>
          <p>99.95$</p>
          <p>Awesome Camera <br> Lenses</p>
          <a href="lenses.html">
              <p>More Info</p>
          </a>
          <a href="index.html">
              <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li>Shop</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid layout in CSS or you can also study how tables in HTML work. This is the grid system applied on the codepen you provided.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="xbox.html"><img src="images/controller.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="xbox.html">
            <h4>Game Controller</h4>
        </a>
        <p>79.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome game controller <br> for xbox!</p>
        <a href="xbox.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="headphones.html"><img src="images/headphones.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="headphones.html">
            <h4>White Headphones</h4>
        </a>
        <p>54.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome white <br> Headphones </p>
        <a href="headphones.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="camera.html"><img src="images/camera.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="camera.html">
            <h4>Cannon Camera</h4>
        </a>
        <p>645.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Camera <br> by Cannon</p>
        <a href="camera.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="microphone.html"><img src="images/microphone.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="microphone.html">
            <h4>Yeti Microphone</h4>
        </a>
        <p>119.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Blue <br> Yeti Microphone</p>
        <a href="microphone.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="cables.html"><img src="images/cables.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="cables.html">
            <h4>Cables</h4>
        </a>
        <p>10.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Cables Available <br> In Different Lengths</p>
        <a href="cables.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product grid-item">
        <a href="lenses.html"><img src="images/lenses.jpg" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="lenses.html">
            <h4>Camera Lenses</h4>
        </a>
        <p>99.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Camera <br> Lenses</p>
        <a href="lenses.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100%;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width:90%;
}
```

Here is a good reference from w3school to study
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    background-color: rgb(240, 231, 231);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 1500px;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: rgba(190, 223, 7, 0.788);
    color: white;
    margin: 30px;
}

header h1, nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header li {
    display: inline;
}

footer {
    padding: 10px;
}
main h2{
    text-align: center;
}
main{
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 270px;
}
.product-container{
  display:flex;
}
.product {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
  width:350px;
  flex-direction:row;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<header>
    <h1>Tech Store</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html">
                <li>Home</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Shop</li>
            </a>
            <a href="contact.html">
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <input type="search" placeholder="search...">
</header>
<aside>
    <h2>Shop By:</h2>

    <section>
        <ul>
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <hr>
            <li>All items</li>
            <li>Cameras</li>
            <li>Laptops</li>
            <li>Phones</li>
            <li>Accessories</li>
            <li>Other</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
        <ul>
            <h2>Price ($)</h2>
            <hr>
            <li>1-9</li>
            <li>10-29</li>
            <li>30-59</li>
            <li>60-99</li>
            <li>+100</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</aside>
<main>
    <h2>All items</h2>
  <div class= 'product-container'>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="xbox.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="xbox.html">
            <h4>Game Controller</h4>
        </a>
        <p>79.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome game controller <br> for xbox!</p>
        <a href="xbox.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="headphones.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="headphones.html">
            <h4>White Headphones</h4>
        </a>
        <p>54.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome white <br> Headphones </p>
        <a href="headphones.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="camera.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="camera.html">
            <h4>Cannon Camera</h4>
        </a>
        <p>645.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Camera <br> by Cannon</p>
        <a href="camera.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class= 'product-container'>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="microphone.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="microphone.html">
            <h4>Yeti Microphone</h4>
        </a>
        <p>119.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Blue <br> Yeti Microphone</p>
        <a href="microphone.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="cables.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="cables.html">
            <h4>Cables</h4>
        </a>
        <p>10.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Cables Available <br> In Different Lengths</p>
        <a href="cables.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <a href="lenses.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
        <a href="lenses.html">
            <h4>Camera Lenses</h4>
        </a>
        <p>99.95$</p>
        <p>Awesome Camera <br> Lenses</p>
        <a href="lenses.html">
            <p>More Info</p>
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h5>Add To Cart</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html">
                <li>Home</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Shop</li>
            </a>
            <a href="contact.html">
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>

</html>
```